# unable to locate etc/apt/sources.list (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: apt, etc

I'm trying to save changes to my `sources.list` file, but it pops up an error message:

```
unable to locate etc/apt/sources.file
```

I also tried using the following commands in order to update the sources.list file

`gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and `sudo apt-get update`

But with no luck. Similarly, the nano editor shows a message:

```
etc/apt directory does not exist
```

Request some help with the issue.

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu keeps the file in `/etc/apt/sources.list`l where as your error message was trying to save it in `/home/$USER/etc/apt/sources.list` which it couldn't do most likely as you hadn't created a ~/etc/apt directory to save it (~ is a shorthand for your user home directory).  You won't have permissions to edit the file directly which is why you need to use `sudo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you open `terminal` it's directory sets to `/home/...` (see the address on your `gedit` it says `/home/madhurya/etc/...`). so if you want to go to `etc` folder you must use <kbd>/</kbd> before it. this should solve your problem:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open the file `/home/madhurya/etc/apt/sources.list`

But the file should be `/etc/apt/sources.list`

So in order to edit the correct file open the terminal and try

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try in terminal to type `sudo -H -s` that  should put you in a root terminal .. then try `cd /etc/apt` and then`ls -la` and see if you can find the `sources.list` and if there are more entries you also may look in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

```
root@home:/etc/apt# ls -la
total 136
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Dec 14 18:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 243 root root 20480 Dec 14 18:06 ../
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec 14 18:30 apt.conf.d/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr  7  2011 preferences.d/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2842 Oct 13 21:33 sources.list
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3500 Nov 19  2012 sources.list~
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec 14 17:59 sources.list.d/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2867 Apr 22  2016 sources.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2842 Oct 13 21:33 sources.list.save
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 39628 Dec 14 18:00 trusted.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 37373 Aug  5 01:12 trusted.gpg~
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 31  2016 trusted.gpg.d/
root@home:/etc/apt#
```